# How i can retrieve a variable value from other file in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am getting var from 1 file to other but its reporting error as undefined var.

I used form to retrieve, using POST method what can i do to get var value.

Form(It has $email & $str value).

```
<form action="resetpassword.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php $email; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php $str; ?>">
</form>
```

Callinginotherfile

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $token = $_POST["token"];
?>
```

Comment: where is the second snippet located? It must be in resetpassword.php (or a script file which is included in resetpassword.php) for it to work. Because the only place you're sending those values to is resetpassword.php. I have just a suspicion that you don't understand that HTTP requests are stateless and that every time you make a request to the server, your PHP code starts again from the beginning and executes as if the previous requests had never happened. Variables are not preserved in memory between executions. If you need to do something like that then use sessions or databases

Comment: I would assume, that there is a scope issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below code.

```
<?php
    $email = (isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "");
    $token = (isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "");
?>
```

Comment: Yup,Now it is not showing any error but its not returning any value.

Comment: do you calling this code in `resetpassword.php` @Lohith

Comment: If i place both in single file it will work but when i try to retrieve from other file it will show undefined index(error).is it possible to get values from form hidden fields,if yes than how ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you put some action to your form then its kinda easy one, but seems in your code you're trying to pass it at the back of the interfaces. Then [Session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) can handle that one.